# Guake is not opening

Tags: linux-mint, guake

Whenever I try to open guake it shows the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/guake", line 24, in 
    import pygtk
ImportError: No module named pygtk
```

How to remove this error and make guake run properly ?

Comment: install the python gtk module.

Comment: How to do so ? I tried using it but it is showing E: unable to locate package pygtk

Comment: The package is `python-gtk2`.

Comment: It is already installed on my computer.It is showing : 

   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   python-gtk2 is already the newest version.
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
</pre>

Comment: Try `python2-gtk2`, maybe `python-gobject-2`. Python version might be wrong against the module version. Alternatively, you may want to check which package provides `pygtk.py` and install more of them: `sudo apt-get install apt-file`, `sudo apt-file update`, `apt-file search pygtk.py`. Try running `python` and typing `import pygtk` on your own to check if it works.

Comment: Nothing is working even after trying all the apt-get commands . 
@TNW: When I do apt-file search pygtk.py , I get :
dreampie: /usr/share/dreampie/dreampielib/gui/load_pygtk.py
python-gobject-2: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygtk.py
python-gobject-2: /usr/share/pyshared/pygtk.py

And by running python and then trying import pygtk It still shows :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygtk

Comment: I am getting this error again and again with other modules also . Please help

Answer (score 1):

I think your system default python is Python3.x, type

```
$ which python
$ which guake
/usr/bin/guake
```

And change the `#! /usr/bin/python` in `/usr/bin/guake` to `#! /usr/bin/python2.7`. Note that guake can be runed just on Python2.x, and the pygtk is just support Python2.x.